# HDMI to DisplayPort Not Working

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport

I have a Macbook Pro and a QHD BenQ monitor here.
Should it be supported to connect these two devices using a HDMI to DisplayPort cable (So HDMI on Macbook DisplayPort on monitor)?

For me it just does not work, I tried replugging checking the channel on the monitor and detect monitors, no cigar.

For now, I'm back to my apple monitor, well a smaller one than I had before since someone snagged that when I was away. But I'd rather use the BenQ because when you're not living in a cave the Apple monitors are a strain on your eyes (glare reflection etc.).

Anyhow my question is in the second paragraph.

Comment: On the MacBook Pro, shouldn't there be a Thunderbolt port? It doubles up as Mini DisplayPort. Have you tried the Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I would go from your mini DisplayPort (mDP) to DisplayPort (DP) or go HDMI to HDMI from your MBP to BenQ.**

The reason why is that DP (newer standard) supports HDMI (older) signaling quite easily through a passive adapter, while going from HDMI to DP requires active conversion.    This is probably the reason it's not working.

I have run into this problem before and what I have found to be reliable is to minimize (at worst) to eliminate (at best) the number of conversions you must do.  If your BenQ has a DP connection, I would use its companion technology, mDP to make my connection.

Comment: Well yes I didn't have an HDMI cable laying around. That's why I tried HDMI to displayPort. Got me a HDMI to HDMI now. Works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely thunderbolt to thunderbolt. Also my BenQ has HDMI so you could do it HDMI -> HDMI

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.