# USB-C to HDMI to DP

Tags: display, usb, hdmi, displayport

I have a MacBook Pro 2017 (two USB-C ports only), running Ventura. I have a USB-C to HDMI female adapter and a HDMI (male) to DP (male) cable to connect everything to a Dell P2415Q. But there arrives no picture on the monitor; it only says 'there is no signal coming from your computer'. The problem persists with different such cables and adapters. Only connecting the adapter to the monitor with a HDMI-HDMI-cable that I borrowed worked. Is there any chance to connect the computer to the monitor with the USB-HDMI adapter and the HDMI-DP cable only?

Comment: Double-adapters rarely work. I'd just bite the bullet & buy a proper cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a USB-C to HDMI female adapter and a HDMI (male) to DP (male) cable

#### This will not work.

What you’re doing is is taking a DisplayPort signal and converting to HDMI which removes the clock signal, then converting it back to DisplayPort which needs one.

What you need is a [quality USB-C to DisplayPort cable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259551/119271).  The linked answer is in relation to a similar question of converting TB3 to TB2 to DisplayPort.  Even though each signal was technically compatible, the multiple conversions proved unreliable.  Your setup is much more complex; converting actual signaling configurations from DP to to HDMI back to DP will likely never work.

#### Further Reading….

- [What's wrong with HDMI?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/398440/119271)
- [Can a USB-C to mini DisplayPort cable be used with USB-C to Thunderbolt ports?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/405047/119271)
- [HDMI to DisplayPort Not Working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/238964/119271)

Comment: Oh, that's really good to know. Now I got a usb-c to DP cable, but only get 4K@30Hz. It's a Dell P2415Q, if that matters. It certainly can do 4K@60Hz over DP, but I don't see how to make the Mac send that. The cable says to support it.

Comment: Your MBP should support four 4K displays at 60Hz.  Make sure you have a DP cable that is version 1.4 or above (2.0] is ideal.

Comment: Is there a way to find out? It should be this: https://www.amazon.de/AmazonBasics-Bi-Directional-USB-C-DisplayPort-Cable/dp/B081VK7Q94 (sorry, I don't find an English page). It says it supports 4K@60Hz, but nothing about a certain DP version. Do you know if there are any specific settings to set?

Comment: It should be written on the cable to be compliant.  I’m not a fan of Amazon Basics because the company take the cheapest product they can find, slap their name on it then promote it as “Amazon Choice”. Try searching for CableMatters DisplayPort cables.

Comment: Okay. Probably that's the issue. There's nothing on the cable.